# lastInsertId() causes program to crash

Tags: php, mysql

so I have this function below. At the very bottom I am returning `$this->conn->lastInsertId()`. If i'm not mistaken this should be correct.

FILE #1

```
 public function insertData($table, $qty, $data){                                                                
    $errors = "";                                                                                            
    $columns = $this->fetchColumnNames($table);                                                              
    $column_list = implode(', ', $columns);                                                                  
    $values = array_fill(0, $qty, '?');                                                                           
    $value_list = implode(', ', $values);                                                                         
    $q = "INSERT INTO $table ($column_list) VALUES ($value_list)";                                                
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($q);                                                                             
    for($i = 1; $i < $qty + 1; $i++){                                                                             
        foreach($data as $key => $val){                                                                           
            if($key == $columns[$i-1]){                                                                           
                try{                                                                                              
                    if(is_numeric($val)){                                                                         
                        $stmt->bindValue($i, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                              
                    }else{                                                                                        
                        $stmt->bindValue($i, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                               
                    }                                                                                             
                }catch(PDOException $e){                                                                          
                    print  $e->getMessage();                                                                      
                }                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                             
    try{                                                                                                          
        $stmt->execute();                                                                                         
    }catch(PDOException $e){                                                                                      
        $errors .=  $e->getMessage();                                                                             
        print $errors;                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                             
    return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
}
```

So moving on to my main file, I have the following line of code

FILE #2

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include '../../inc/config.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplication.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplicationQuery.php';
$processor = new ProcessApplicationQuery($CONN);
$processor->insertData("full_application", 17, $general);
if($processor->getConn()){
    list($general, $phones) = $processor->processGeneralInfo($_REQUEST['general_information']);
    print $processor->insertData("full_application", 17, $general);
}
```

If I remove the return line from File #1 and just print in File #2 nothing happens, and the program inserts into the database like so. For some reason this return line is causing the entire program to fail and 404. It's very odd I have never had this occur, so why would this return line cause this error?

===UPDATE===

So even weirder I have added the follow items to my files
FILE #1

```
 public function insertData($table, $qty, $data){                                                                
    $errors = "";                                                                                            
    $columns = $this->fetchColumnNames($table);                                                              
    $column_list = implode(', ', $columns);                                                                  
    $values = array_fill(0, $qty, '?');                                                                           
    $value_list = implode(', ', $values);                                                                         
    $q = "INSERT INTO $table ($column_list) VALUES ($value_list)";                                                
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($q);                                                                             
    for($i = 1; $i < $qty + 1; $i++){                                                                             
        foreach($data as $key => $val){                                                                           
            if($key == $columns[$i-1]){                                                                           
                try{                                                                                              
                    if(is_numeric($val)){                                                                         
                        $stmt->bindValue($i, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                              
                    }else{                                                                                        
                        $stmt->bindValue($i, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                               
                    }                                                                                             
                }catch(PDOException $e){                                                                          
                    print  $e->getMessage();                                                                      
                }                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                             
    try{                                                                                                          
        $stmt->execute();                                                                                         
    }catch(PDOException $e){                                                                                      
        $errors .=  $e->getMessage();                                                                             
        print $errors;                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                             

}

public function getApplicationid(){
    $query = "SELECT id FROM eagle.full_application ORDER BY create_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $id = null;
    foreach($this->conn->query($query) as $row){
        $id = $row['id'];
    }
    return $id;
}
```

FILE #2

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include '../../inc/config.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplication.php';
include 'ProcessApplication/ProcessApplicationQuery.php';
$processor = new ProcessApplicationQuery($CONN);
$processor->insertData("full_application", 17, $general);
if($processor->getConn()){
    list($general, $phones) = $processor->processGeneralInfo($_REQUEST['general_information']);
    $processor->insertData("full_application", 17, $general);
    echo $processor->getApplicationId();
}
```

I added a new method, and attempted to print it. I still get the error in which the files 404. It is really odd. I hope this helps out on the solution, because I am stumped.

Comment: Nothing in the error logs?

Comment: I don't have access to the error logs, but it produces no errors other than the 404. It's basically not hitting the file

Comment: Oh, so you don't know if there is anything in the error logs. It is going to be hard to troubleshoot without access to the error logs. Do you have all error reporting turned on?

Comment: edited my last comment

Comment: Your Return-line is unfinished.. lastInsertId is a function, the brackets are missing as well as the semikolon...

Comment: hmmm I had them in there when I typed it up, that's not the cause of the error though, that's just a typo

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: did that, and it literally did nothing to help. Basically it's like the file is never being hit. This error literally causes a complete 404 of the directory. It's frustrating. Also if I remove the return line, and keep the print line from my main file the same. it proceeds to work. So....

Comment: **$** print $processor->... ?? Is this still in PHP context?

Comment: yes I have edited the quest to add more content, but yes we are still in PHP context.